# ProxyError, when trying to query prometheus behind the proxy

Tags: python, python-requests, prometheus

I am coding a module that needs functionality to query Prometheus, when Prometheus is sitting behind proxy and module is making queries from my local environment. My development environment is in Virtual Machine, with correct environment variables and DNS -settings, and is able to talk with the Prometheus behind the proxy for example with accessing the front-end GUI.

I've tested my requests.get() method, when its executed on the network behind the proxy and it is returning the correct values, so I am pretty positive that the proxy is causing the problem, for some reason I dont get the program to respect the proxy dictionary I am feeding to requests. I am using Visual Studio Code and Python 3.9.7.

When executing the code at the bottom of this post, I am getting loads of errors, in which the last one is this one: (Cleared some values, such as the proxy servers, url and query out, due to privacy reasons, they're correct and in-place in my code)

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))
```

Relevant Python Code:

```
    import requests
    import json

    http_proxy  = ''
    https_proxy = ''
    ftp_proxy   = ''

    proxies = { 
                "http"  : http_proxy, 
                "https" : https_proxy, 
                "ftp"   : ftp_proxy
                }

    headers = {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    
    response = requests.get(url='' + '/api/v1/query', verify=False, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, params={'query': ''}).text
    j = json.loads(response)
    print(j)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's are several bugs open regarding the missing or bugged support for `no_proxy` for Python Requests (ex: [#4871](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/4871), [#5000](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5000)).
The only solution for now AFAICS is coding the missing logic in a function like the following one:

```
import json
import requests
import tldextract  

http_proxy  = "http://PROXY_ADDR:PROXY_PORT"
https_proxy = "http://PROXY_ADDR:PROXY_PORT"
no_proxy    = "example.net,.example.net,127.0.0.1,localhost"

def get_url(url, headers={}, params={}):
    ext = tldextract.extract(url)
    proxy_exceptions = [host for host in no_proxy.replace(' ', '').split(',')]

    if (ext.domain in proxy_exceptions
        or '.'.join([ext.subdomain, ext.domain, ext.suffix]) in proxy_exceptions
        or '.'.join([ext.domain, ext.suffix]) in proxy_exceptions):
        proxies = {}
    else:
        proxies = {
            "http"  : http_proxy,
            "https" : https_proxy,
        }

    response = requests.get(url=url,
                            verify=False,
                            headers=headers,
                            params=params,
                            proxies=proxies)
    return response

url = "https://example.net/api/v1/query"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

response = get_url(url, headers)
j = json.loads(response.text)
print(j)
```

Comment: I have correct proxy servers in my real code, but in this example I've scraped them away due to privacy reasons. Sorry, I'll edit that to the original post.

Comment: Ok :) I added a more complete answer meanwhile.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I am still getting the error. after the modifications you suggested. I've tried now to use .env -varibles, and load the proxy settings from there, but with no luck. I am starting to think this has something to do with out environment and not the code or proxy itself ... Continuing to investigate.

Comment: That's weird, the option `no_proxy` seems to be ignored... So the only option I see is disabling the proxy for local addresses by setting `proxies = None`.

Comment: @marjakuusi My new answer with some code to work-around the issue of missing support for `no_proxy` in Python Requests.

Comment: Thank you Davide! I will test these modifications at the morning. :)

Comment: @marjakuusi Did you test it?

Comment: Im sorry, that it took a while to get back, I've been busy. I will test it right away.

Comment: Still getting the same ProxyError. I am really starting to think that this is not due to the code anymore, but something I need to do in our environment in order to get through the proxies ... I'll do some research internally and get back to you.

Comment: Did you set a correct `no_proxy` string? I was able to simulate the error and solved it using this code.

Comment: Sorry for disappearing, I was very busy with other work and basicly had to completely abandon project which had this issue. Thank you very much still for taking time to debug this.